# machine learning to predict equations / parameters of equations

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, continuous-data

I'm not sure if machine learning is the best way to do this, but I'm interested in seeing if this problem is feasible. Normally you use machine learning for classification. ie.given the size of a tumor and the color(darkness) of the tumor, determine whether its lethal or benign. However, say you want to figure out how the tumor has been growing/how it will end up in the future,  given that you know its current size and current color.

Can you use machine learning to predict an equation or curve that describes its size, for the duration of the tumor's life?

This is how my data looks:

```
Subject   SIZE  COLOR   GROWTH
1          5      10    3.4/(1+t^-1.2)
2          8      62    3.8/(1+t^-1.5)
3          15     77    6.5/(1+t^-3)
4          40     94    8.6/(1+t^-15)
…          …      … …
```

Comment: To clarify a point in the answer below that might not be entirely clear: the case described in the question falls more within the category of traditional statistics than machine learning - though of course there is overlap.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regression to estimate the parameters of the equation (if you know the equation it is called parametric model). Just in a way you do that for a simple regression: set two parameters as a target variable.

```
Subject   SIZE  COLOR   target parameter 1   target parameter 2
1          5      10    3.4                  -1.2
2          8      62    3.8                   1.5
3          15     77    6.5                  -3
4          40     94    8.6                  -15
```

In case of non-parametric model (so you don't know what are the parameters), you can still apply some metric algorithms that would return for a new data point the combination of the given curves.

Just for example, if you have three points $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ in a training set (with a given curves $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$, $\phi_3$), and you receive one new point $x_4$, that lies somewhere in the middle between $x_1$ and $x_2$, then probably $(\phi_1 + \phi_2)/2$ would be a good answer.